# Почему зависает программа в SFML c++

Tags: c++, sfml, mingw, codeblocks

Я хотел сделать игру Timber в SFML используя книгу ["Beginning C++ Game Programming - Second Edition"](https://edu.anarcho-copy.org/Programming%20Languages/CPP/Beginning%20C++%20Game%20Programming%20-%20Second%20Edition.pdf). Но когда я запускаю игру отображается в заднем плане изображение но игра немного зависает и "программа не отвечает" и выводится в консоль:

```
Process returned -805306369 (0xCFFFFFFF)   execution time : 9.799 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Вот код:

```
// Include important C++ libraries here
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

// Make code easier to type with "using namespace"
using namespace sf;

int main()
{
    // Create a video mode object
    VideoMode vm(1280, 800);

    // Create and open a window for the game
    RenderWindow window(vm, "Timber!!!", Style::Fullscreen);

    // Create a texture to hold a graphic on the GPU
    Texture textureBackground;

    // Load a graphic into the texture
    textureBackground.loadFromFile("graphics/background.png");

    // Create a sprite
    Sprite spriteBackground;

    // Attach the texture to the sprite
    spriteBackground.setTexture(textureBackground);

    // Set the spriteBackground to cover the screen
    spriteBackground.setPosition(0, 0);


    while (window.isOpen())
    {

        /*
        ****************************************
        Handle the players input
        ****************************************
        */

        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Escape))
        {
            window.close();
        }

        /*
        ****************************************
        Update the scene
        ****************************************
        */


        /*
        ****************************************
        Draw the scene
        ****************************************
        */

        // Clear everything from the last frame
        window.clear();

        // Draw our game scene here
        window.draw(spriteBackground);

        // Show everything we just drew
        window.display();


    }

    return 0;
}
```

Но когда я изменяю:

```
if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Escape))
    {
        window.close();
    }
```

На:

```
Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
```

Программа не зависает. Почему может быть так?
Я использовал Code::Block и MinGw

Comment: Ничего удивительного. Состояние "программа не отвечает" говорит о том, что она не обрабатывает оконные сообщения.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста сказать почему так бывает?

Comment: Так бывает потому, что кто-то не обрабатывает оконные сообщения...

Comment: Извините, я новичок и не понял кто должен обрабатывать оконные сообщения..?

Comment: Оконные сообщения должно обрабатывать приложение.

Comment: Но когда я исползовал window.pollEvent это работало

Comment: Правильно, `pollEvent` - это и есть обработка оконных сообщений.

Comment: Я писал этот код используя книгу и про это там небыло

Comment: @FazliddinShuxratillayev видимо, там об этом забыли

Comment: Возможно, надеюсь что так

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот что об этом написано [на сайте самого SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/window-window.php):

> A mistake that people often make is to forget the event loop, simply because they don't yet care about handling events (they use real-time inputs instead). Without an event loop, the window will become unresponsive. It is important to note that the event loop has two roles: in addition to providing events to the user, it gives the window a chance to process its internal events too, which is required so that it can react to move or resize user actions.

Перевод:

> Ошибка, которую часто совершают люди, заключается в том, что они забывают о цикле обработки событий просто потому, что они еще не заботятся об обработке событий (вместо этого они используют ввод данных в реальном времени). Без цикла событий окно перестанет отвечать на запросы. Важно отметить, что цикл обработки событий имеет две роли: помимо предоставления событий пользователю, он также дает окну возможность обрабатывать свои внутренние события, что необходимо для того, чтобы оно могло реагировать на перемещение или изменение размера пользователем.